# If $T$ is diagonalizable and $c_1,…,c_k$ are distinct eigenvalues of $T$, then minimal polynomial of $T$ is $(x-c_1)\dotsb (x-c_k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

> Let $V$ be $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $T\in L(V,V)$. If $T$ is diagonalizable and $c_1,…,c_k$ are distinct eigenvalues of $T$, then $m_T=p=(x-c_1)\dotsb (x-c_k)$.

**My attempt:** We need to show $p$ is monic, $p(T)=0$ and if $f\in F[x]$ such that $f(T)=0$, then $\deg (p)\leq \deg (f)$. Clearly $p$ is monic. By theorem 3 section 6.3, $c_1,…,c_k$ are roots of $m_T$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4588481/861687) post, $k\leq \deg (m_T)$. It’s easy to check, $\deg (p)=k$. So $\deg (p)\leq \deg (m_T)\leq \deg (f)$. We claim $p(T)=0$. Since $T$ is diagonalizable, $\exists B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ basis of $V$ such that $\alpha_i$ is eigenvector of $T$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Let $\alpha_i\in B$. Then $\exists c_j\in F$ such that $T(\alpha_i)=c_j\cdot \alpha_i$. Since $F[x]$ is commutative [linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4519932/861687) over $F$, we have $p=(x-c_1)\dotsb (x-c_k)=(x-c_1)\dotsb (x-c_{j-1})(x-c_{j+1})\dotsb (x-c_k)(x-c_{j})$. So $p(T)=(T-c_1I)\dotsb (T-c_jI)$. Since $(T-c_jI)(\alpha_i)=0$, we have $[p(T)](\alpha_i)=0$. Since $\alpha_i$ was arbitrary, $[p(T)](\alpha_i)=0$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Thus $p(T)=0$. By uniqueness, $m_T=p$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: The question is somewhat ambiguously stated. It should make explicit the assumption that $c_1,\dots,c_k$ are *all* the eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah I agree you. In Hoffman and Kunze book word distinct is used that’s why I use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can see no errors in your argument, I would say it achieves this easy result in a rather roundabout way. Note for instance that you introduce an arbitrary annihilating polynomial $f$ but never really use it in the argument; you go straight for the minimal polynomial $m_T$ instead. Which is valid if you know that the minimal polynomial exists: any monic annihilating polynomial whose degree does not exceed that of the minimal polynomial *is* the minimal polynomial, though there is an smell of circularity when using that in an argument.

I would use the main fact about polynomials in $T$ and eigenvectors instead, namely that $P[T](v)=P[\lambda](v)$ for any polynomial $T$, whenever $T(v)=\lambda v$. For a polynomial $P(T)$ in a diagonalisable $T$ to be $0$, it suffices that it kills all eigenvectors (for it will then be zero on the sum of eigenspaces, which is the whole space), and for this one must have $P[\lambda]=0$ whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Clearly the minimal degree monic polynomial with this property is the product of factors $X-\lambda$ for $\lambda$ running over all distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Your points are valid. Hoffman’s define minimal polynomial in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4595342/861687) way. So we know existence & uniqueness of minimal polynomial for $T$. Minimal polynomial $p$ for $T$ is uniquely determined by following three properties: (1) $p$ is monic, (2) $p(T)=0$, (3) if $f\in F[x]$ such that $f(T)=0$, then $\deg (p)\leq \deg (f)$. Property (2) & (3) is equivalent to $M_T=\{f\in F[x] \mid f(T)=0\}=pF[x]$. Latter definition has smell of circularity, as you suggested. Second paragraph: your proof is really elegant.